# sudo whitelist just program perl

Tags: web-application, linux, web-service, privilege-escalation, sudo

In visudo Ubuntu I whitelist this program

```
myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/myuser/program.pl
```

when I run

```
sudo /myuser/program.pl
```

I get prompt to set password. The solution is to add to visudo /usr/bin/perl

```
myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/myuser/program.pl,/usr/bin/perl
```

Now I can run without asking the password.

Here is the problem; when I run my web service system with the user as myuser
the web service can run any commands as `/usr/bin/perl` for example

```
/usr/bin/sudo  /usr/bin/perl -e 'system ("cat /etc/shadow");'
```

Is my assertion correct?
What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, your assertion is correct. As for the solution...good question

Comment: You'd better never let anyone run an interpreter as root without password...

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue you need to modify this line:
`myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/myuser/program.pl,/usr/bin/perl` 
Into this one:
`myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/perl /myuser/program.pl`

Comment: are you seriously? that is not the solution

Comment: Yes .For me is the solution because `myuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/perl /myuser/program.pl` will let you run only `/usr/bin/perl /myuser/program.pl` as root whitout password.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/221192/sudo-parameterised-all-commands-is-this-secure

Answer (score 0):

First of all: do not run the webserver under a user-ID that you use interactively. That is a very bad practice. Especially, if your interactive sessions use sudo-s.

Normally, `sudo` uses per-tty authentication, so your assessment is correct if your webserver is launched from the same tty as from where you are `sudo`ing, or if your `sudoers` contains `Defaults !tty_tickets`.

If you really need to run the webserver under your own name, and from the same tty, you will need to set the time-out for `sudo` to 0. From `man sudoers`:

> > sudoers uses per-user time stamp files for credential caching. Once a user has been authenticated, a record is written containing the uid that was used to authenticate, the terminal session ID, and a time stamp (using a monotonic clock if one is available). The user may then use sudo without a password for a short period of time (5 minutes unless overridden by the timestamp_timeout option). By default, sudoers uses a separate record for each tty, which means that a user's login sessions are authenticated separately.